# How to write a class destructor in Scala?

Tags: scala, destructor

I'd like to have a FileWriter opened during the whole time a class instance exists. So I need to close it in a destructor. But how to specify a destructor in Scala?

Comment: Given that you do not destruct objects in Scala (or Java), and there's no guarantee the object will ever be deallocated, what would be the use of specifying a destructor?

Comment: I suggest that tying the duration of the stream to an instance is conceptually wrong from the get go.  You should have resource's duration tied to execution scopes.  I.e. you should always close the resource in the very same scope in which it is opened.

Answer (score 10):

You might be interested to check out Josh Suereth's scala-arm project, which provides both monadic and delimited-continuation based resource management for just this source of use: http://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm

If you really think that you need a destructor (i.e. because you think you need to create the object and then hand it off and never see it again) I'd recommend reconsidering your application architecture instead... there is simply no way to make this work reliably on the JVM.

Comment: The general pattern for resource management is the loaner (aka borrower) pattern.  Resource duration is bounded by scope.  When the borrower exits, the resource is destroyed.  It's really shocking how long it's taken mainstream languages to provide a good expression for this critical design pattern.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a handy utility method I use frequently.  I find that it unclutters my code nicely.

```
def closer [T, C <: Closeable] (c : C) (f : C => T) : T = 
    try f (c)
    finally c.close
```

Using it is dead simple. The example, below, consumes an input stream from a URLConnection.  Instead of connection.getInputStream you could create any arbitrary stream, of course (or, more generally, any arbitrary closeable object).

```
val bytes = closer (connection.getInputStream) { istream =>
        val bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream ()
        val buffer : Array [Byte] = new Array (1024)
        Iterator.continually (istream read buffer).takeWhile (_ > 0).foreach (bytes write (buffer, 0, _))
        bytes.toByteArray
    }
```

This version will operate on anything with a close method (needn't implement Closeable or anything else).

```
def autoClose[R <: {def close()}, T](resource: R)(use: R => T): T = {
  try use(resource)
  // Don't want an NPE here masking an exception from use.
  finally Option(resource).foreach(_.close())
}
```

Here are some implicit classes to do the job.

```
implicit class AutoCloseBracket[R <: Closeable](resource: R) {
  def autoClose[V](use: R => V): V = try use(resource) finally resource.close()
}
implicit class AutoCloseableBracket[R <: AutoCloseable](resource: R) {
  def autoClose[V](use: R => V): V = try use(resource) finally resource.close()
}
```

Comment: Isn't it amazing how FP can lead code to become completely un-pronouncable:
_Iterator continually inputstream read buffer take while it is greater than zero for each bytes write buffer from zero it_ 

Comment: Contrast with Kotlin's `somethingCloseable.use`

Comment: It may be wacky to read but in Java that's a dozen lines of code.  Plus, it was much harder to write than it is to read it.

Answer (score 8):

Scala doesn't have destructors. It has finalizers, like Java, but they're not the same thing at all. There is also an interesting blog series in emulating C#'s `using` keyword in Scala here:

- [Hey Scala, Finalize This](http://naturalsoftware.blogspot.com/2009/06/hey-scala-finalize-this.html)
- [Scala Using RAISIN](http://naturalsoftware.blogspot.com/2009/06/scala-using-raisin.html)
- [More Scala Using RAISIN](http://naturalsoftware.blogspot.com/2009/06/more-scala-using-raisin.html)

Comment: See also the [`Closeable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface (specifically for IO), and the up-coming (Java 7) more general [`AutoCloseable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

Comment: @Matthew: Don't you think that's more of an alternative answer than a comment on my answer?

Comment: @matthew-flaschen do you mean a FileWriter object will auto close when it's GCd?

Comment: @marcelo-cantos Using doesn't look good because it is to be used inside a method, opening and closing a file every time I call it. I think this will ruin overall performance as it is going to be called very very frequently. I want one FileWriter object to be opened all the time.

Comment: @Ivan: Can you instantiate the FileWriter in the outer loop and pass it in (either as a parameter on each call or assigned to a field)?

Comment: @marcelo-cantos I can hardly imagine how to implement it this way and not make my code ugly. Actually now I have "write" method in the class and store a FileWriter in the class's private field. "write" method initializes the FileWriter if it isn't initialized, writes data and leaves it open, so I need to close it somewhere.

Comment: @Ivan: Then you'll just have to go for the traditional make-sure-you-close-the-door-on-your-way-out approach used since the earliest days of C.

Comment: @marcelo-cantos I've got an idea! I myself am going to implement Closeable, so that upstanding code will close my class instance it has created, and I can close the file in my class's close method.

Comment: There's an arm library, as Kris have indicated: http://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm

Answer (score 2):

As I noted above, Java has an existing [`Closeable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface specifically for IO, which you could adopt.  This doesn't provide any sugar, but it will help people use your class correctly.

In Java 7, `Closeable` will be a subinterface of [`AutoCloseable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).  `AutoCloseable` is a more general interface for any resource that needs to be closed after use while potentially throwing an exception.  it is part of the planned [Automatic Resource Management](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_arm_api) support in Java 7.  Less relevant to your question (since you're using Scala), there is also supposed to be new [Java syntax](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/04/java-7-updates-project-coin/) (an extension of existing try blocks) for this scenario.